Boolean modifier doesn't work well
I want to make some patterns on this object (pants)

But after hiding the curves not all of them leave marks

How can I fix it?
This is my blend file


Could you share just the relevant objects in a stripped-down file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ? There are a few possible causes, and we can't just guess.

Please share a Blend file which just includes the pants and objects you have used for the boolean modifiers.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Have you tried setting the Solver from Exact to Fast in the Boolean modifier?

Yes, I've tried change the Solver. I just added a blend file

File the holes of these cylinders, your objects need to be manifold:

Also the scale of your object is bad, apply it to bring it back to 1/1/1 (CtrlA) then in Edit mode select all and recalculate the normals (ShiftN):

At last activate the Hole Tolerant option of the Boolean:


Thank you very much for your time! It helps me.
